# How does this line " return self.last_block['index'] + 1 " works?

Tags: python, blockchain

I'm learning to create a blockchain system and cannot understand how this line fits into this code.
Why and how last_block() is used with 'index'?

class Blockchain(object):
    def **init**(self):
        self.chain = []
        self.current_transactions = []

```
def new_block(self):
    pass

def new_transaction(self):
    pass

@staticmethod
def hash(block):
    pass

@property
def last_block(self):
    pass
```

block = {
    'index': 1,
    'timestamp': 1506057125.900785,
    'transactions': [
        {
            'sender': "8527147fe1f5426f9dd545de4b27ee00",
            'recipient': "a77f5cdfa2934df3954a5c7c7da5df1f",
            'amount': 5,
        }
    ],
    'proof': 324984774000,
    'previous_hash': "2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824"
}

def new_transaction(self,sender,recipient,amount):
    self.current_transactions.append({
      'sender' : sender,
        'recipient':recipient,
        'amount':amount
    })

```
return self.last_block['index']+1
```

Comment: That is a very partial code snippet at best. Please check that this code is really representative of what you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to
https://hackernoon.com/learn-blockchains-by-building-one-117428612f46 to implement the blockchain, view the full source code at https://github.com/dvf/blockchain/blob/master/blockchain.py. 
On line 142 and 143 you see the following lines of code

```
 def last_block(self):
    return self.chain[-1]
```

Which clearly indicate how

> return self.last_block['index']+1

works